# Nginx will not start because I made a mistake and don't know how to reverse it

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I am following [this tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-deploy-a-react--flask-project) in order to learn how to deploy flask-react applications from a singe nginx server, but I made the mistake of trying this command: `$ sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/react-flask-app.nginx /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/react-flask-app.nginx`, but it happens that my file has no `nginx` extension, so the command should have been `$ sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/react-flask-app /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/react-flask-app`. Now nginx refuses to start with command `sudo systemctl start nginx`, and command `systemctl status nginx.service` returns the following:

```
Dec 14 16:32:21 ip-172-31-5-99 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Dec 14 16:32:21 ip-172-31-5-99 nginx[2017]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/react-flask-app.nginx" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62
Dec 14 16:32:21 ip-172-31-5-99 nginx[2017]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Dec 14 16:32:21 ip-172-31-5-99 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 14 16:32:21 ip-172-31-5-99 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 14 16:32:21 ip-172-31-5-99 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

I don't know how to instruct nginx to forget about that file, I already stopped, started and reloaded nginx.

Answer (score 0):

I found that a file with the name `react-flask-app.nginx` was created in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`, and such file contains the error message. I only deleted the file and everything went back to normal.